# ¿Se usa "kilo" como "millón" en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica

En los tiempos en que la peseta era la divisa en España se decía coloquialmente "un kilo" para significar "un millón de pesetas".

> El Madrid ha pagado 50 *kilos* por ese jugador nuevo.

El motivo es que mil billetes de mil pesetas pesaban casi un kilo (1000 gramos), y dicen que [fue el torero Manunel Benítez "el Cordobés"](http://www.abc.es/hemeroteca/historico-15-08-2006/abc/Economia/un-kilo-ya-no-es-un-millon-de-pesetas-sino-73_1422878646846.html) quien hizo "el descubrimiento". El término se mantuvo con la llegada del euro.

> [Florentino](http://futbol.as.com/futbol/2013/08/22/primera/1377208308_716774.html) se ha gastado casi 1000 "kilos" en sus 50 fichajes (1000 millones de euros)

A pesar de que la RAE [mantiene el significado de "millón de **pesetas**"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Mh281FW).

El Diccionario de americanismos [no recoge ese significado](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=kilo) de "kilo". ¿Significa eso que esa acepción coloquial de "kilo" no se usa y no se entiende?, ¿o que no se usa pero es posible que se entienda, dependiendo del país?

Comment: En la ciencia, "kilo" quiere decir mil.  Un kilogramo = mil gramos.  Un kilómetro = mil metros.  Kilowatt.  Etc., etc.  Esto va muy bien de acuerdo con mil billetes de mil pesetas.

Comment: Pues te digo una cosa: desde la llegada del euro he dejado de escuchar completamente la palabra "kilo" para designar un millón (de pesetas o de euros). Antes sí se usaba mucho, pero ya no. Imagino que también será porque antes era más fácil gastarse un kilo en algo (un coche, por ejemplo). Ahora es prácticamente imposible salvo que sean movimientos empresariales o inversiones en viviendas de lujo, por poner.

Comment: @aparente001 Eso es cierto, pero el origen del coloquialismo es, efectivamente, el que da Diego en su pregunta: el peso de un millón de pesetas en billetes de mil.

Comment: @Gorpik de hecho, recuerdo allá por el milenio pasado cuando estaba en BUP (o COU) una práctica de laboratorio en la que pudimos pesar un billete de 1000 pesetas en una báscula de precisión, y pesaba prácticamente un gramo (la diferencia era del orden de miligramos). Por tanto, 1000 billetes pesaban casi exactamente un kilo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, completamente de acuerdo, por eso me he tenido que ir al fútbol y Florentino Pérez para encontrar a alguien que gaste "kilos" de euros... :-D Pero el ejemplo ahí está. Ese artículo es de 2013. Como llevo ya varios años fuera de España, a veces dudo, como en este caso, de si no se usaba o si yo no recuerdo o qué. RAE incluso especifica "de pesetas", pero me preguntaba hasta que punto habría agarrado este coloquialismo en otros países hispanoamericanos.

Comment: Physics lessons must have been more interesting when @CarlosAlejo was a boy.

Answer (score 10):

Respondo por Argentina solamente, en principio: *kilo*, además de ser un prefijo, sólo se usa para *kilogramo*. No he escuchado en ningún otro lugar de América *kilo* como sinónimo de muchas unidades monetarias.

Como referencia, en Argentina (y creo que en Chile) mil unidades monetarias locales (pesos o lo que fuera) se llaman coloquialmente una *luca*. Cien unidades son una *gamba*. Un millón son un *palo* (si son dólares, un *palo verde*).

Comment: "Luca", "gamba" y "palo". Esta respuesta es _oro_. Hay alguna razón? Quizá el color de los billetes de 100 es rosadito como uan gamba?

Comment: @Diego En Argentina *gamba* es lunfardo por "pierna" (del italiano). Ni idea.

Comment: Efectivamente también lo decimos así en Chile. "Un millón" también se dice "un guatón", que literalmente significa "un gordo" (derivado de la lengua mapuche). Y como actualmente casi nada vale cien pesos, la palabra "gamba" está un poco en desuso.

Comment: _Luca/Lucas_ así como _palo_ también se usan en Colombia. Nunca se usa _Kilo_ para referirse a una cantidad de dinero.

Answer (score 4):

En México, he escuchado frecuentemente a la gente que trabaja áreas relacionadas con finanzas y mercado de valores, referirse a un kilo como millón, aunque usado solamente en conversaciones informales.

Por ejemplo, un kilo de pesos, se refiere a un millón de pesos.

Fuera de ese ambiente, no lo he escuchado.

Comment: Me acaba de decir un amigo que se dedica al mercado de valores, que también se dice "palo" para referirse a un millón, justo como en la respuesta de pablodf76, la única diferencia sería un palo *de* verdes para USD

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde yo se, en Latinoamérica no se hace referencia de cantidades de dinero con relación a su peso. La situación es que confunde escuchar en la actualidad y hasta como se escribe (mil = k), cuando se refieren básicamente a la compraventa de jugadores con ese nivel de valor: 40k = 40 "millones", lo cual no se ve como algo congruente. Está bien para los españoles, ya explicaron lo de las pesetas y todo eso, pero en los demás países, no procede.