# ¿Se entiende "no tengo ni un duro" en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica, colombia

A raíz de esta pregunta [¿Se usa “kilo” como “millón” en Hispanoamérica?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/se-usa-kilo-como-mill%C3%B3n-en-hispanoam%C3%A9rica) me surgió una similar recordando algo que escuché hace años.

Para quien no lo sepa, en España, cuando teníamos pesetas llamábamos *duro* a la moneda de 5 pesetas, lo utilizabamos también como medida de referencia: cinco duros, veinte duros,... mucha gente incluso en cifras más grandes: 10.000 duros, 20.000 duros, etc.

El caso es que la expresión *no tengo (ni) un duro* para decir que no tienes dinero era muy común, hoy todavía se usa. Lo que me extrañó es oírsela a un colombiano (quizá no era colombiano pero español seguro que no) hace como 20 años. ¿Se la escuchó decir a algún español y se la apropió o se utiliza en Colombia u otros países de América?

Comment: Me extrañaría. El DLE muestra en [_duro_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIKtetO) _Esp. Moneda de cinco pesetas_, luego la acepción es solamente propia de España. En el DAMER por [_duro_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=duro) no encuentro nada parecido. En general, creo que se usa siempre _no tengo un peso_. Buscando [_no tengo un duro_](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=no%20tengo%20un%20duro) en Google Trends solo encuentro resultados pertenecientes a España. Dicho todo esto, ¡buena pregunta! A ver qué comentan nuestros compañeros de Hispanoamérica.

Comment: Yo he oído a algunos españoles usar "_no tengo un [chavo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8fvlroy|8fyCpPs)_", que entiendo que es una situación similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En el momento solo puedo hablar por Colombia y la respuesta es no. Tal vez el "presunto colombiano" que conociste o no lo era o estaba "españolizado"

Aquí diríamos.

- No tengo ni un peso
- Estoy en la inmunda
- No tengo ni cinco / Estoy sin cinco
- No tengo ni en que caerme muerto.
- Estoy *líchigo*  (En Antioquia se entiende. En otras regiones *líchigo* es tacaño)

Comment: Vale, entonces o me falla la memoria y no era colombiano o copió la expresión a un español. O quizá ambas cosas XD

Comment: En México tampoco se usa. Las frases equivalentes son muy parecidas a las de Colombia

Comment: Igualmente en Chile, excepto lo de _la inmunda_ y _líchigo_. Además decimos _ando pato_.

Comment: Por lo que decís y lo que he buscado por mi cuenta parece que no se usa esa expresión ni en Colombia ni en otros países hispanohablantes. Supongo que la persona a la que escuché decirlo lo aprendió de españoles.

Comment: Estas expresiones colombianas se entienden y usan exactamente igual en México excepto *Estoy líchigo*. Pero tenemos la expresión *Ando bruja* que es equivalente.

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente, encuentro la frase perfectamente comprensible.

> No tengo ni un _______

Un mexicano no usaría la palabra **duro** porque no es una denominación actual o antigua en México. Se entenderá perfectamente siempre y cuando el que escucha reconozca la palabra que sigue como una denominación de dinero. Debido a que las denominaciones son variables, no es necesario que sea el nombre de una moneda de curso actual; por ejemplo **quinto** o **centavo**.

Si el que escucha no reconoce la palabra como denominación monetaria, entonces no comprenderá a menos que pueda adivinar el significado por el contexto; p. ej.

> – Cómprame ese vestido
> – ¿Cómo quieres que te lo compre si no tengo ni una luz?

Aunque no descarto que el oyente se quede un poco confundido o no entienda.

En Mexico, también existen expresiones retóricas que ayudarían a un mexicano a comprender por el contexto. p. ej.

> Me gustaría comprarme esta casa pero no tengo ni en qué caerme muerto

En México sí funciona con papas, y me atrevo a decir que quizá con nabos.

> quisiera un auto nuevo pero no tengo ni una papa.

Con zanahorias, definitivamente no funciona. Sería, en el mejor de los casos, una situación cómica.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con @motilio que no se usa en México, pero aún así, cualquiera que hable español puede entender la frase, y eso es lo que se preguntó.

Muchos van a entender que *duro* es algún tipo de moneda, quizás de España, quizás de antaño.  Pero aún sin entender *duro*, si Pedro dice algo de la forma

> No tengo ni un _______

van a entender que Pedro está sin fondos.

Comment: No creo que eso pueda aplicarse de forma general. Se pueden poner montones de palabras en la frase *no tengo ni un ____* que no tengan nada que ver con el dinero. Si no sabes que es un duro no creo que se entienda la frase.

Comment: @blonfu - Aunque no sepa uno qué es un duro, la palabra fácilmente se podría entender como algún tipo de moneda, por *la dureza* de las monedas. // No tengo ni una zanahoria.  No tengo ni un foco.  No tengo ni un lápiz.  Todas estas frases funcionan para mí.

Comment: «No tengo ni una zanahoria. No tengo ni un foco». Yo no relacionaría ninguna de esas dos frase con dinero sin mas contexto. Si estamos hablamos de ir a cenar y me dices *No tengo ni una zanahoria*, entonces sí, sé que hablas de dinero. Por eso tu respuesta me parece también interesante pero creo que se necesita algo más de información.

Comment: @blonfu - No para argumentar, sino por curiosidad, ¿cómo interpretarías los ejemplos que dí, en la situación en que no hay más contexto?

Comment: Si me dices «no tengo ni una zanahoria» pensaría que no tienes comida en casa y necesitas hacer la compra. Para mí un foco es [esto](http://www.marcatuproducto.com/uploaded_images/334462983.jpg) y se me haría raro que alguien usara la palabra foco en esa frase, no sabría muy bien que pensar.

Comment: Aún así creo que en parte tienes razón, en muchos casos se entendería que hablamos de dinero. Y si usamos *estoy sin un ____* todavía estaría más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Decir que en mi país, Argelia se dice esta expresión, "duro" para referirse a los
5 céntimos antiguos. Igualmente decimos no tengo ningún duro, para expresar que no tengo dinero.

Comment: La pregunta es _en Hispanoamérica_, no en Africa.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión que hace referencia al **duro**, ahora quizá haya que actualizarla, por otra que ya se usaba antes:

> **No tengo (ni) un céntimo**

Answer (score 1):

Yo diría que se entiende, pero no se usa.
Esto es verdad al menos para todos los que hayamos tenido algún mínimo roce con el vocabulario usado en España sea por TV, música, cine o personal. Otras palabras, como 'chaval' por ejemplo, corren la misma suerte: son españoladas y te mirarían raro si las dices pero nadie va a preguntar que significa.

Es curioso que cada país y región tiene una frase equivalente. En Cuba sería "no tengo ni un kilo prieto, partido por la mitad". Un kilo (o quilo?) representa la moneda de un centavo y un centavo prieto sería mas viejo y con bajo o ningún contenido de níquel lo que lo haría lucir oscuro (prieto). Partido por la mitad no necesita explicación...