# ¿Por qué "duro" en España significa "dinero"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa

En esta pregunta: [¿Se entiende "no tengo ni un duro" en Hispanoamérica?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22002/se-entiende-no-tengo-ni-un-duro-en-hispanoam%C3%A9rica) se menciona que

> ... en España, cuando teníamos pesetas llamábamos duro a la moneda de 5 pesetas, lo utilizábamos también como medida de referencia: cinco duros, veinte duros

Como lo mencionan las respuestas y comentarios allí, al parecer la expresión es usada solo en España, por lo que yo no la conocía. ¿Cómo vino "duro" a significar una cantidad específica de dinero? ¿Era de uso coloquial o podías hablar formalmente refiriéndose a "duros"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

La peseta fue la moneda de curso legal en España desde el 19 de octubre de 1868 hasta la llegada del euro. Antes de esa fecha, la denominación *peseta* existía pero como nombre de una moneda. Así, monedas de curso corriente eran:

- la **peseta** (diminutivo de *peso*), que equivalía a 4 reales de vellón,
- el **peso**, que equivalía a 8 reales de vellón, y
- el **peso fuerte** o **peso duro**, que equivalía a 20 reales de vellón.

Si te fijas, un peso duro equivalía a 5 pesetas. Ya en el siglo XIX se encuentran textos que hablan del peso duro simplemente como "duro", por abreviar. Esa denominación perduró en el tiempo, de modo que hasta la desaparición de la peseta el 1 de enero de 2002 se siguió llamando "duro" a las monedas de 5 pesetas.

Ejemplos de su uso ya en el siglo XIX:

> *El dia 27 del pasado á cosa de las nueve de la noche, se extravió del segundo piso de casa Montagut, calle de Abaixadors, una perrita carlina jóven de un año, con una mancha en la cola, orejas mal cortadas y de color claro: el sugeto que la haya recogido tenga la bondad de devolverla en dicha casa, que se le dará un duro de gratificación.*
>
> Diario de Barcelona, 1 de abril de 1820.

Esto es en cuanto a la relación entre el apelativo "duro" y la moneda de 5 pesetas. En realidad la denominación de "duro" viene de mucho antes: por ejemplo la moneda de "[real de a 8](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_de_a_8)", acuñada ya en 1497, también se denominaba "peso fuerte" o "peso duro".

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, dado que "duro" era parte del nombre oficial de la moneda, se podía hablar de "duros" incluso en ámbitos formales (aunque imagino que en entornos muy formales se preferiría la denominación completa "peso duro"). Eso sí, una vez desapareció el peso duro y prevaleció la peseta, la denominación pasó a un ámbito ya más coloquial. Al menos mientras yo viví las pesetas, así lo era: se podía usar coloquialmente hablando e incluso en textos no formales dado que era un apelativo cariñoso. Pero formalmente siempre se debía hablar de "pesetas". Así, un anuncio como el mostrado en el ejemplo de 1820, si se hubiera escrito en un periódico de 1990 no se habría hablado de una gratificación de 200 duros, sino de 1000 pesetas.

Comment: A mi abuelo materno siempre le oí hablar de reales y duros, nunca de pesetas.  También de "perras", "perras gordas" y "perras chicas".

Answer (score 4):

Hay una pequeña incorrección. El orígen del nombre peseta no es exclusivamente diminutivo de peso, como dice el compañero @Charlie, sino que tiene dos orígenes.

Tal y como se explica en [¿De dónde proceden los nombres de las monedas del mundo?](http://www.unitedexplanations.org/2016/04/11/de-donde-proceden-los-nombres-de-las-monedas-del-mundo/):

> Existen dos posibles orígenes etimológicos del nombre de la divisa: uno indica que la palabra peseta procede del vocablo catalán peceta​ ('piececita'), diminutivo de peça ('pieza'), nombre con que se conocía desde el siglo XV a algunas monedas de plata y que más tarde designó al real de a dos. El otro, recogido por la Real Academia Española, apunta que peseta es simplemente un diminutivo del vocablo peso,​ nominación que recibían las antiguas monedas españolas de plata y de donde procede el nombre de las actuales unidades monetarias de diversos países americanos.

Comment: Hola Javi y bienvenido al sitio. Te he editado la respuesta para mostrar que una parte está tomada de otro sitio (asumo que de [¿De dónde proceden los nombres de las monedas del mundo?](http://www.unitedexplanations.org/2016/04/11/de-donde-proceden-los-nombres-de-las-monedas-del-mundo/)). Gracias por tu contribución y hasta pronto. Por cierto: ¿llegaste vía Menéame?

Comment: Hola @fedorqui Si, llegué aquí vía Menéame y el texto lo saqué de la wiki, que a la vez lo sacó de la web que pusiste tú. Muchas gracias por editar la respuesta!